# Oracle SQL Subquery seems to not work when ececuted with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have an sql statement that gets executed from a python script using cx_Oracle. This statement includes two subqueries like this:

```
select distinct
 us.firstname as "Vorname",
 us.lastname as "Nachname",
 us.email as "Email",
 us.loginname as "Q-Nummer",
 us.status,
 us.lastlogintime
from 
 user_table us
where
 us.lastlogintime >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -7)
 and us.lastlogintime < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -6)
 and not exists (select distinct sp.user_id from specificstatus sp where sp.user_id = us.id)
 and not exists (select distinct ec.owner_id from electriccomponent ec where ec.owner_id = us.id)
```

I get a different number of results, depending on whether I run this sql statement in my python script or directly in sql developper. It seems the python script does not execute the two subqueries, for when I comment those out in sql developper, the result is identical with the one from the python script. What could be the reason for this?

Edit: the python code is nothing special:

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(cfg.db_hostname, cfg.db_port, sid=cfg.db_servicename)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=cfg.db_username, password=cfg.db_password, dsn=dsn_tns, encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
conn.autocommit = True
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(cfg.sql_query)
```

Comment: Most probably you are in 1) different database or 2) use different connect user or 3) you see some uncommited changes not visible in other sessions. This is *your job* - no one on SO can help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but: it is the same database and the same connect user. Also, as I have written, if I omit the subqueries in sql developper I get exactly the same results as with the python script.

Comment: we probably need to see your python code here

Comment: I added the python code.

Comment: Show us what _exactly_ is in `cfg.sql_query`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you may be connected to a different database or as a different user, or there may be uncommitted data in one or the other environment. You need to verify that -- by executing a query that fetches data that you have just added in SQLDeveloper in a Python script (for example). You can also perform these queries as an initial check in both environments:

```
select sys_context('userenv', 'service_name') from dual
```

```
select sys_context('userenv', 'current_user') from dual
```

It is highly unlikely that a query executed in one environment will simply "fail" to execute in another environment -- barring a serious bug, of course! The SQL is simply sent to the database without any manipulation.

You can also set the environemnt variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value `16` and make sure that the SQL that you are executing is in fact the SQL that you *think* you are executing!